# Save specific pages of an Excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have one workbook with three sheets. Each sheet got 3 pages. What I want to reach is: I want to save only the first page of each sheet.

I can only count those pages with

```
int numberOfPages = 0;

foreach(Excel.Worksheet sheet in excelWorkbook.Sheets)
{
    numberOfPages += sheet.PageSetup.Pages.Count;
}
```

But I cant find a way how to save these pages. Is there a way?

Comment: You want to save only one page of your file? You want to keep your pages in memory? you want to make a new file that contains only the first page of each file?

Comment: I want to save the pages into a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to copy a worksheet:

```
Excel.Worksheet worksheet1 = ((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1]);
Excel.Worksheet worksheet3 = ((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[3]);
worksheet1.Copy(worksheet3);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the Macro Recorder in such cases (which is available in Excel). The required VBA code can generated automatically in the background for you. Most probably you will need to correct it because an auto-generated code is not well-optimized, but at least you will have an idea what properties and methods should be used to get the job done. See [Create or delete a macro](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-or-delete-a-macro-2841ba85-9da6-4bd7-93a4-0da90844f283) for more information.